# openni2_tracker and Nite2

Tags: ros, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the openni.org website is no longer available, where can I download the nite2 needed for the openni2_tracker package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187651/openni2_tracker-and-nite2/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if you'll find what you're looking for here, but the openni website was migrated to http://www.openni.ru.

EDIT: I should have also provided a link to Occipital's "structure.io" site: http://structure.io/openni.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpennNI releases can be found here on Github: https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/releases
PrimeSense drivers here: https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/releases
Official primesense drivers: https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/releases

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2